# How to edit attributes of lvdisplay (LVM)

Tags: lvm

In a lvdisplay command, there is an attribute to display the hostname of the machine we created the logical volume.
I want to modify the hostname. how can I modify "LV Creation host" attribute in lvdisplay?

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. backup your data
2. edit `/etc/lvm/backup/yourvgname`, and identify
   your lv section in the `logical_volumes` config snippet
3. fill in the `creation_host` parameter with your new string, save & quit your editor
4. `vgcfgrestore yourvgname`